# visual studio 2015 publish output setup.exe has error

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio, stimulsoft

I create a Winform C# app with visual studio 2015 
my database is postgresql 
actually my app has two button for show some reports and that reports designed by **Stimulsoft Report** vr 2019.1.1 Trial 
so my app in visual studio 2015 is work but when I publish and then try for install the output file I mean setup.exe , I faced by this error 
so what should I do?

[image: after try for install setup.exe]

Comment: @Robll I don't know what should I do Step by Step !

Answer (score 1):

There is installation file on https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/releases/tag/v2.2.7.
Choose one you need and install it.